# How do you make a counter to count the number of even and odd numbers entered by user?

Tags: c++

I have this code so far that is supposed to keep asking the user for a number until they type 0. Then the program will tell the user how many odds and evens they typed. I cannot get the latter function to work correctly. Any tips? I am a beginner, so please no advanced ways to solve this :D

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{

    int n;
    int myCounter1, myCounter2;
    cout << "Odds and Evens\n\n" << endl;
    do
    {
        cout << "Please enter an integer: ";
        cin >> n;

        myCounter1 = 0;
        myCounter2 = 0;
        if (n%2 == 0)
        {
            myCounter1++;
        }
        else 
        {
            myCounter2++;
        }

    }
    while (n!=0);
    cout << "You entered " << myCounter1 << " even numbers, and " << myCounter2 << "odd numbers " << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is not working correctly? [ask] - [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple things:

- Code indentation (or lack thereof) makes this really hard to read. Indentation is not only cosmetic, but can help in understanding code.
- You are setting the counter variables to zero each time the loop runs. Declare them outside of the loop so they retain their values.
- The `else` clause of the `if` statement has erroneous syntax. Use a simple `else` instead, as there are only two cases for the parity of `n`.
- When the user types `0` to exit the loop, it too is counted as an even integer. Add a condition in the `if` statement to account for this.

Applying these changes yields this code:

```
int n;
int myCounter1 = 0, myCounter2 = 0;
cout << "Odds and Evens\n\n" << endl;
do {
    cout << "Please enter an integer: ";
    cin >> n;

    if (n%2 == 0 && n != 0)
    {
        myCounter1++;
    }
    else
    {
        myCounter2++;
    }

} while (n!=0);
cout << "You entered " << myCounter1 << " even numbers, and " << myCounter2 << "odd numbers " << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

This

```
        else n == 0
        {
            myCounter2++;
        }
```

should be

```
        else
        {
            myCounter2++;
        }
```

Honestly, I don't even know why it didn't grab your attention, since it can't compile.

Also, you shouldn't set the counters to zero in the loop. So

```
    int myCounter1, myCounter2;
    cout << "Odds and Evens\n\n" << endl;
    do
    {
        cout << "Please enter an integer: ";
        cin >> n;

        myCounter1 = 0;
        myCounter2 = 0;
```

should be

```
    int myCounter1=0, myCounter2=0;
    cout << "Odds and Evens\n\n" << endl;
    do
    {
        cout << "Please enter an integer: ";
        cin >> n;
```

And, finally, since you probably shouldn't count the 0 as one of the integers entered...

```
    cout << "You entered " << myCounter1-1 << " even numbers, and " << myCounter2 << " odd numbers " << endl;
```

Comment: @F-15 If the number of evens is one more than it should be, then you should do the last thing I mentioned, because otherwise the 0 is included as well.

Actually, can you send me an example input where the code breaks, what it prints and what it should print?

Comment: Okay thanks! That worked. In the future I should not put numbers at the end of my variables I guess?

Comment: I got it. I think it was because of my variable name myCounter1?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 bugs and 1 syntax error. 
line:`else n == 0` should be simply `else`

The 2 bugs are related to your counters:
1) You have to exclude the 0 input from the counters.

2) Every time you are reading a number your are setting them (the counters) to zero, which means that you will always ending with zero and one.

Answer (score -1):

Here it is for anyone interested:

## include

using namespace std;

int main ()
{

```
int n;
int myCounter1 = 0;
int myCounter2 = 0;
cout << "Odds and Evens\n\n" << endl;
do
{
cout << "Please enter an integer: ";
cin >> n;


if (n%2 == 0)
{
myCounter1++;
}
else
{
myCounter2++;
}

}
while (n!=0);
cout << "You entered " << myCounter2 << " odd numbers, and " << myCounter1-1 << " even numbers " << endl;
```

return 0;
}